# Android cyclic listeners

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-seekbar

I've got a small issue in my code:

I've a `SeekBar` and an `EditText` in a layout.
What I want to do is to set the `EditText` value when the `SeekBar` changes and set the `SeekBar` progress when the `EditText` changes.

So far, I've the following code:

```
    SeekBar seek_coagulation = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_coagulation);
    EditText edit_coagulation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_coagulation);
    seek_coagulation.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seek_coagulation.setMax(1000);
    seek_coagulation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            double value = progress / 100.0;
            edit_coagulation.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }
    });
    edit_coagulation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            double value = (s != null && s.toString().length() > 0) ? Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.')) : 0D;
            int progress = (int) (value * 100);
            seek_coagulation.setProgress(progress);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }
    });
```

The first case (`SeekBar` to `EditText`) works well, but not the second.
The problem is that it is a loop (`SeekBar` to `EditText` to `SeekBar` to `EditText` etc.).

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: I think you have choose some another approach liek take one button which will set EditText value to seekbar when buttin click instead of EditText addTextChangedListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use two boolean parameters to lock changes, like this:

```
    boolean mIsTextLocked = false;    
    boolean mIsSeekBarLocked = false;

    seek_coagulation = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_coagulation);
    EditText edit_coagulation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_coagulation);
    seek_coagulation.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seek_coagulation.setMax(1000);
    seek_coagulation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            if(!mIsSeekBarLocked){
               mIsTextLocked = true;
               double value = progress / 100.0;
               edit_coagulation.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
           mIsTextLocked = false;
        }
    });
    edit_coagulation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
           if(!mIsTextLocked){
            mIsSeekBarLocked = true;
            double value = (s != null && s.toString().length() > 0) ?Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.')) : 0D;
            int progress = (int) (value * 100);
            seek_coagulation.setProgress(progress);
            mIsSeekBarLocked = false;
           }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }
    });
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.